# Show that $2 ^ n - 1$ divides $3 ^ n -1$ if and only if $n = 1$

Tags: arithmetic

My idea was: If $n$ is even, 
$\gcd (3ⁿ-1; 2ⁿ-1) = 
\gcd (6ⁿ-3ⁿ + 3ⁿ-1; 2ⁿ-1) = 
\gcd (6ⁿ-1; 3ⁿ-1) = 2ⁿ-1 $

So $3ⁿ-1 = 2ⁿ-1$ So $3ⁿ = 2ⁿ$, what does $n = 0$ (nonsense pq gets 0/0)

$3ⁿ-1 \equiv 0 \mod 2ⁿ-1$, so $3ⁿ \equiv 1 \mod 2ⁿ-1$, i.e. $3 \equiv 1 \mod 2ⁿ-1$,  $2 \equiv 0 \mod 2ⁿ-1$.

Someone help me?

Comment: $\gcd(6^n-1,3^n-1) = 2^n-1$ is false for $n=2$: $\gcd(35,8)=1 \ne 3$.

Comment: $\gcd(3^n-1,2n^-1)=\gcd(6^n-1,2^n-1)$ whether $n$ is even or not.   Why do you say $\gcd(6^n-1, 3^n-1) = 2^n-1$?

Comment: If $n$ is even then $2^n-1$ is divisible by $3$ but $3^n-1$ is not

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A086892

Comment: How does $3\equiv 1\pmod{2^n-1}$ follow from $3^n\equiv 1\pmod{2^n-1}$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130823/when-does-2n-1-divide-3n-1