# For $n > 1,$ show that $2^n - 1 \nmid 3^n - 1$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> For $n > 1,$ show that $(2^n - 1) \nmid (3^n - 1)$.

I know how to show the result in the case that $n$ is even. In that case, $2^n - 1\equiv 0 \mod 3,$  but $3^n - 1\not\equiv 0\mod 3$, so $2^n - 1 \nmid (3^n-1).$ However, I'm not sure how to deal with the case when $n$ is odd. I just need to show that there is a prime factor dividing $2^n - 1$ that does not divide $3^n - 1$, or equivalent that $\gcd(2^n-1, 3^n - 1) < 2^n - 1.$  Maybe some group theory, Fermat's little theorem, the Euler fermat-theorem, etc. might be useful?  Would it be useful to show that $n \nmid 2^n - 1$ for $n \ge 1$?

Comment: I only find a similar problem [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1922770p13187420). But the method used in solving that one does not apply here. Note that $2^n - 1$ can be a prime number, (conjecturally) for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130823/when-does-2n-1-divide-3n-1) is a duplicate, though I have not checked the answer.  There's a solution using the extended law of quadratic reciprocity (extended to composite moduli) which might well be correct, but that technique can be treacherous so I advise checking it.

Comment: @lulu Nice find. I checked that the answer there is correct.

Comment: @WhatsUp  Thanks for checking it.

Comment: @WhatsUp Kudos for checking it. Many prior answers can be (iteratively) refined and improved in this manner - which is one of the ways that dupe-checking helps to greatly improve site quality (and encourages us to ponder generalizations and relationships that might not have been obvious).

Comment: @lulu Great to see you assisting in site organization.